# How to apply diffrent css style on different events of an asp button?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a web user control where I have ten asp buttons.

I want that when I hover on these buttons the cursor should change to hand cursor, I am able to do that.

Now I want that when I press a button it should change it's back and fore colors so that it looks selected.

I tried to do that by code but it's not working. Following is my css file content:

```
.buttonclass
{
    background-color: Olive;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selectedItemClass
{
    background-color: Blue;
    color: White;
}
```

and on the button click I have written like:

```
 Button btn = sender as Button;                
 btn.CssClass = "selectedItemClass";
```

but it's not working any idea or another way to achieve the required behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work after post-back, and then the button will remain with the `selectedItemClass`.

You will need to use client-side code to change the class of your button.

One option would be to use a javascript/jquery solution like:

```
$(".buttonclass").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selectedItemClass")
});

$(".buttonclass").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("selectedItemClass")
});
```

Comment: Hi Curt, ur solution works but it's applied to all buttons i want to apply it only for the clicked button...any idea how to do it ?

Comment: You could create a unique class for each button like: `class="buttonclass button1"`, then change `buttonclass` to `button1` in the jquery code

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the class is added or replaced? or you can do:

```
.selectedItemClass
{
    background-color: Blue!important;
    color: White!important;
}
```

to check if the order of your css is ignoring the fact there are two different background-color and the priority of them.